# Cast an unmodifiable set

Tags: java, casting, unmodifiable

I have a java.lang.Object that I can't cast. When debugging I notice that the Object is an unmodifiable set so I tried to cast it to a set but that didn't work (ClassCastException). Instead I tried

```
Set<SimpleUserBean> listOfSelectedItems = new HashSet<SimpleUserBean>(object)
```

But of course that isn't possible either since there is no such constructor for HashSet.

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Why cannot you cast it? What's the output when you use `System.out.print(object.getClass().getName())` and `System.out.println(object.getClass().getTypeName())`? You could also use `Class<?> interfaces = object.getClass().getInterfaces` and get the info of the object at runtime to see what super type you may cast it in order to ease your work.

Comment: Are you sure you are casting the object to Set<SimpleUserBean> and not some  kind of concrete Set?

Answer (score 2):

If the Object is a `java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableSet` or anything else that implements `Collection`, then you should be able to do `new HashSet<>((Collection) object)`. That makes it clear to the compiler that you're trying to use the `HashSet(Collection<? extends E> c)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> Set listOfSelectedItems = new HashSet(object)

This is not possible. How about this.

```
Set<SimpleUserBean> listOfSelectedItems =  new HashSet<SimpleUserBean>();
listOfSelectedItems.addAll((Collection)object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableSet` to `String arrays`.

Use :

```
object.getValue().toString().replace("[","").replace("]","").split(":")
```

Assuming `object.getValue()` will give you `java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableSet`